# Anyone knows of a tutorial on how to remove/replace the radio and AC unit in a 2001 Subaru Legacy?

Tags: ac, subaru, replace, audio, legacy

I have new radio and AC units for my 2001 Subaru Legacy L Station Wagon but I do not know how to install them. It seems more complicated than I expected. Does anyone knows of a good tutorial or manual on how to remove and replace those two?

Comment: What part of the AC unit are you trying to replace, the compressor? If so, there are a few specialized tools you'll need to complete this. Such as a vacuum pump and an A/C manifold to check pressures, to name a couple. If you don't have these and really don't know the process, I'd highly suggest you take your work to a qualified shop. Not something an average backyard mechanic can attempt and complete successfully.

Comment: The radio is a piece of cake, to be honest. The hardest bit is popping the dash without scratching it, but then it's obvious. As far as a/c goes, the dash module is as easy as the radio, but as Paulster says, replacing the actual guts of the thing is not for beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the radio goes, you can use this [tutorial](http://how.coffee/how-to/how-to-replace-the-stock-radio-in-a-2001-subaru-legacy-l-station-wagon-with-step-by-step-pictures/). If you just want to replace the AC front panel box I am sure you can figure it out using the same tutorial. But as said in the comments, if you want to work with the AC unit itself, better take it to a shop.